# Rails 3.1 Uglifier gem not working

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to get uglifier working for JavaScript compression working on localhost dev environment.  I have looked at the rails guide and couple of other posts and all seem to point to the config setting:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

config.assets.compress=true
```

I've tried these settings and a couple of variations and nothing seems to work.  After viewing my gem list, these are all installed and each one is required in the Gemfile. I'm not really sure what else to try.

Could it possibly be my config settings?

Comment: Just in case: You have read that you need ExecJS - supported runtime installed? See at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, section 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a javascript runtime, e.g.

rubytheracer (deprecated)
node
execjs

This was new in rails 3.1